# Struts2 validation is not even working

Tags: struts2

I also configured all the setting for Struts2 basic validation, but nothing is working for me.

My login.jsp file

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <s:head />
  </head>
  <body>
    <s:actionerror/>
    <s:form action="Login" method="post">
      <s:textfield name="userName" label="User Name" />
      <s:password name="password" label="Password" />
      <s:submit value="Login" />
      <s:fielderror></s:fielderror>
    </s:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

My loginAction class is,

```
package com.test;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public LoginAction() {
    }

    public String execute() {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

my struts2.xml file is,

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="Login" class="com.test.LoginAction" method="execute">
        <result name="SUCCESS">login.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

And I place my LoginAction-validation.xml file in the same package where the Action class is placed.

Please lookout my code and help me to resolve the validation issue.

Comment: Are you using the default template of Struts2? Can you put your `LoginAction-validation.xml` and what are you testing with?

Comment: WHAT is not working for you ? Post your XML file please

Answer (score 0):

You are returning same login.jsp page in your execute method in action class.
So this results in displaying login page with empty field every time you hit enter.

Try creating an additional jsp to which you are redirected to based on String returned from action class.

other than that i dont see any problem.